# Can someone please explain the logic of this C# code that involves the 'passing by output' concept?

Tags: c#, oop

```
static int Test(out int x, int y=4) 
{
    x = 6;
    return x * y;
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int a;
    int z = Test(out a);
    Console.WriteLine(a + z);
}
```

The output is 30, but I do not understand exactly how.

I get that in the Test() method, the parameter x outputs the value of 6 into the Main() method, but how, if you are just outputting the 6 does it send the return value of 24?

I don’t know if that all made sense. I am struggling with this whole “pass by output” concept, I guess.

Please try to explain this concept in the simplest Barney-style way possible. If it’s overly technical and complicated, it will likely just confuse me more.

Comment: Well it's setting `a` to 6 and *returning* 24 due to the return expression of `x * y`. So `a` is 6 and `z` is 24. Which one of those do you not understand? That will help us to help you.

Comment: I am guessing that the code is missing the second parameter to "Test" as "Test(out a, ??).  As i guess it will not matter since it gets set to 4 any way? Just a thought.

Comment: Jon: I guess I was confused because I thought that when it said 
int z = Test(out a) that it would only be pulling the value of x, not the whole return statements value. So, I was thinking that z =6, not 24.

Comment: JohnG - that is part of what confused me. But I'm thinking that since the 2nd parameter is already declared and initialized in the Test() function, it doesn't need to have a second argument in the function call?

Comment: Jon - I actually ordered your book on Amazon and I'm waiting for it to arrive! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments below:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int a;
    int z = Test(out a); // returns z as 6 * 4 = 24 and sets a = 6;
    Console.WriteLine(a + z); // 24 + 6 = 30
}
```

`out` allows developer to pass and update a parameter value by reference, so that it is reflected in the caller method (same as `a` in your case)

From C# Specifications:

> A parameter declared with an **out** modifier is an output parameter. An
>   output parameter does not create a new storage location. Instead, an
>   output parameter represents the same storage location as the variable
>   given as the argument in the function member or delegate invocation.
>   Thus, the value of an output parameter is always the same as the
>   underlying variable.

The difference between `ref` and `out` is that:

> • Every output parameter of a function member or anonymous function
>   must be definitely assigned before the function member or anonymous
>   function returns normally.